# CPU Utilization & Memory Utilization script

Tags: cpu

I want to show CPU & Memory utilization. Like I use command of `mpstat` and get an output:

```
01:04:19 PM  CPU   %user   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal   %idle intr/s
01:04:19 PM  all    9.30    0.00    2.44    2.06    0.10    0.55    0.00   85.55
```

I need a script to show only the value of %idle. In which the Idle value is minus by 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `%idle` is the 11th column. To see all the rows where the idle percentage is below 100 you can use:

```
mpstat 1 |awk '$11<100'
```

If you are only interested in the value of the idle percentage column you can use:

```
mpstat 1 |awk '$11<100{print $11}'
```

Comment: This is the output which I got

%idle
99.49
99.49
99.49
99.50
99.49
.
.
.
so on